# In VS Code, why am I observing syntax-highlighting bugs in Java code that align to the same column?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image: Example screenshot 1]

(courtesy of https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/17pxrpm posted by u/chopfab__)

[image: Example screenshot 2]

(courtesy of https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16szhue posted by u/NeighborhoodNo8750)

Notice how the syntax-highlighting issues are aligned to specific columns. I have several Java extensions installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue stemming from the [`georgewfraser.vscode-javac`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgewfraser.vscode-javac)- possibly when combined with the [`redhat.java`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension- at least- [from the experience](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/17pxrpm/comment/k88ufov) of [u/chopfab__](https://www.reddit.com/user/chopfab__/). Consider just disabling `georgewfraser.vscode-javac` as they did. You might not need it if you already have another Java language support extension enabled. If you originally installed it because you were looking for more Java extensions to try, note that [Oracle also released one in 2023](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/). You can also search "`@category:"programming languages" java`" in the Extensions View. I have no affiliation with any of these extensions.