VSCode syntax highlight and other features are garbled
Frequently, VSCode garbles the syntax highlighting in my code:

When this happens, other features like code completion also fail (e.g., it will not give me a context menu after I type a period after an object, but it will give me such a menu if I type a period in a comment; it doesn't provide hints to the arguments of a function, etc.). It also handles tabs/spaces incorrectly and throws errors about using tabs/spaces inconsistently.
Typically if I wait long enough (a few minutes) it will correct itself, then start acting up again in a few minutes.
What might be causing this, and how can I fix it?

reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77440687/11107541, but probably not related

It does seem very similar, although I'm working in Python not Java, so I wouldn't know which extensions might be causing the problem in this case.
